# Automatically add source files in a scala jar

Tags: scala, jenkins, sbt, sbt-assembly

I am trying to add source files to a scala jar. The jar is generated nightly with Jenkins, using sbt to compile and sbt-assembly to make the jar. Any idea how I could make Jenkins automatically add the source files in the jar ?

Answer (score 2):

You can add your source files to your .jar with SBT by adding this line to your build.sbt file:

```
unmanagedResourceDirectories in Compile <+= baseDirectory( _ / "src" )
```

For more information, see:

- http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Howto-Customizing-Paths.html
- https://doc.overops.com/docs/viewing-the-source-code-in-overops